# Converting sound of recorded audio into byte array in Android

Tags: android, audio, fft, mediarecorder

I am developing an Android music identification app like Shazam. I searched online and I found a lot of articles. But the best one I found is https://www.toptal.com/algorithms/shazam-it-music-processing-fingerprinting-and-recognition because it has simple code, explained as a tutorial and clearly explained.

But in android, I cannot follow the code exactly because some code does not has in android and some are different in syntax. As you can see in the link, it record the sound and finally convert that into byte array. But in android, what I am doing is I recorded the song using MideaRecorder and save it into a media file with .3gp or .mp3 extension. Now I am saving as .3gp. In the link I am following, it directly record the sound and convert the sound data(Frequency, Vibration and so on) into byte array.

What I am actually doing in android is trying to convert media file into byte array. So my question is, when I convert the audio file into byte array, will I get the sound data that need to be processed like in Shazam? Can I do that? The way I am doing is right? Can I do Fourier Transform on that byte array received from recording?

I am recording sound like this:

```
        outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/recording.3gp";

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();
```

I am trying to convert that file into byte array for FFT.

Comment: _"and save it into a media file with .3gp or .mp3 extension"_ Android doesn't have an mp3 encoder (not by default anyway). Your current settings where you're using AMR-NB are probably not such a good idea, because AMR-NB is limited to 8000 Hz and very low bitrates. If you want uncompressed PCM, then why not use the [`AudioRecord` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) instead?

Comment: But converting the file to byte array can still be used for TTF process? And so please what settings and I should use with Audio Record? Please can I have a sample code?

Comment: `AudioRecord` doesn't save the data to a file. You get chunks of data in a `byte[]`, which you can then write to a larger buffer until you have enough data, or whatever you want to do with it. For sample code, use google.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much.